# How to get a selected TreeViewItem by click only in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

I spent long time already looking for a simple and straight answer but failed so far. I found mixed answers that would help me but all of them would generate a huge ammount of code for something that is really, really simple:

**How can I get the selected item by a click in a WPF treeview?**

I already know how to get the selected item or how to select an item by right button click or how to delay the item selection by key (all answers found around here), but I just want to know when the user clicks the item. That's is needed because I have a treeView where the user can navigate with arrow keys (which will change de IsSelected), but I just have to execute some logic when the item is clicked or the Return key is pressed.

I'd love a pure MVVM solution. If that's not possible, I'm quite desperate here so anything not monstrous would help.

Comment: Don't think it's as simple as your guessing it to be. What qualifies as a click? MouseDown / MouseUp / MouseDown & UP on same item without moving to another item or outside bounds of `ListBox` itself. Quite a few variations to what a "Click" generally corresponds to. If you have the exact specifics of what your treating as a Click, You can then capture that event on your `ListBox` and then get the `SelectedItem` property provided `SelectedItem` is updated before the `RoutedEvent` for your requirement is invoked.

Comment: and once the above is met, if you want it to be without code-behind and more mvvm'ish, Then wrap all the event handling in a `Behavior`.

Comment: @Viv I mean click in a general way, it doesn't matter what exactly, I just want to know that was by mouse and not by keyboard. And yes, already done with sucess using events in code-behind and already saw the Behaviar solution... As I said, I'm looking for a native and simply solution (that I'm starting to believe doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for example if you consider `MouseDown` as your Click, you could do something like:

xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="testListBox">
  <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="B" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
</ListBox>
```

code-behind:

```
testListBox.AddHandler(MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler((sender, args) => ItemClicked()), true);
testListBox.AddHandler(
  KeyDownEvent,
  new KeyEventHandler(
    (sender, args) => {
      if (args.Key == Key.Enter)
        ItemClicked();
    }),
  true);

private void ItemClicked() {
  MessageBox.Show(testListBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
}
```

With this the `MessageBox` will only be invoked when the Mouse was pressed on the `ListBoxItem` or Enter Key was pressed. Not when arrow keys change Selection. `SelectedIndex` will hold the correct Index on the shown `MessageBox`.

**Update:**

A MVVM way using Behaviors:

```
public class ItemClickBehavior : Behavior<ListBox> {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickedIndexProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ClickedIndex",
      typeof(int),
      typeof(ItemClickBehavior),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(-1));

  public int ClickedIndex {
    get {
      return (int)GetValue(ClickedIndexProperty);
    }
    set {
      SetValue(ClickedIndexProperty, value);
    }
  }

  protected override void OnAttached() {
    AssociatedObject.AddHandler(
      UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler((sender, args) => ItemClicked()), true);
    AssociatedObject.AddHandler(
      UIElement.KeyDownEvent,
      new KeyEventHandler(
        (sender, args) => {
          if (args.Key == Key.Enter)
            ItemClicked();
        }),
      true);
  }

  private void ItemClicked() {
    ClickedIndex = AssociatedObject.SelectedIndex;
  }
}
```

xaml:

```
<ListBox>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:ItemClickBehavior ClickedIndex="{Binding VMClickedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="B" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
</ListBox>
```

Now the Property `VMClickedIndex` will have the Index of the ListBox that was "Cicked" / "Enter Key Hit" on

Comment: @RogerKiihl I've updated my answer with a Behavior that should give you a Bindable field(`VMClickedIndex`) for just these Clicked / Enter key invoked SelectedIndexes

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm still surprised it's not something easier but as my previous search showed me and your answer demonstrates, there's good options.